# Display Nested json in select Dropwdown angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Im new to angular and struggling to display nested json object in select dropdown. This is my json object.

```
[
  { 
    "cuisine":{ 
      "cuisine_id":1035,
      "cuisine_name":"Afghan"
    }
  },
  { 
    "cuisine":{ 
      "cuisine_id":1,
      "cuisine_name":"American"
    }
  }
]
```

And in my component HTML im displaying like this

```
<select class="form-control dropdown" name="processTemplate" id="processTemplate">
  <option *ngFor="let cuisineList of cusine1 | keyvalue">
     {{ cuisineList.value.cuisine_name | json }}
   </option>
 </select>
```

I would like to display only cuisine_name in select dropdown. Not sure where im going wrong. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is the posted JSON is a valid one?

Comment: Yes @PrashantPimpale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<select class="form-control dropdown" name="processTemplate" id="processTemplate">
  <option *ngFor="let cuisineList of cusine1 | keyvalue">
     {{ cuisineList.value.cuisine.cuisine_name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uttpak?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`{{ cuisineList.value.cuisine.cuisine_name }}`

since you need to access *cuisine_name* of each *cuisine* object .

Comment: a little correctionn **cuisineList.value.cuisine.cuisine_name** as she is using keyvalue pipe

Answer (score 0):

Grab the json array in a variable. Let's the variable is **cuisines**. Now Follow the snippet.

```
<select class="form-control dropdown" name="processTemplate" id="processTemplate">
  <option *ngFor="let cuisineList of cuisines">
     {{ cuisineList.cuisine.cuisine_name}}
   </option>
 </select>
```